# Cross Domain Pop Ups

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, porthole.js

My flow is as follows: the user clicks sign in on site 1. a pop up is opened from site 2 asking him to login using twitter. he then logs in - using oAuth, so the page changes. After a successful login the pop up should close and the code on site 1 should receive a notification.

**What didn't work:**

- **WebIntents** - well, the examples on their site didn't even work, so I didn't try it locally..
- **easyXDM** - communicates with an iframe, not a popup.
- **porthole** - same, uses an iframe.

A horrible solution is refreshing the iframe every couple of seconds, to check if the user logged in already.

Is there a better way to do this? better libraries?

Comment: What didn't work about WebIntents?

Comment: the examples on their website! http://examples.webintents.org/

Comment: well, I'm using firefox 10 and nada =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can refer the popup to another page after the user is logged in, you could use this:

**main page:**

```
localStorage.setItem('user_signed_in', false); // signed out by default
window.open("http://www.google.com/", "google_window", "menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,width=400,height=300");

(function look_up() {
  if(localStorage.getItem('user_signed_in')) {
    go_on();
  } else {
    setTimeout(look_up, 500)
  }
}());

function go_on() {

...

}
```

**refer page:**

```
localStorage.setItem('user_signed_in', true);
window.close();
```

Keep in mind that the refer page has to be on the same domain as your main page.
And, don't be afraid of bad support for localstorage in [other browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage),
but if you really want to support oldies, you [can use cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage), I believe.

Comment: So, i'll need a pop up and an iframe. oh internet.

Comment: Why would you need an iframe?

Comment: "Keep in mind that the refer page has to be on the same domain as your main page" - because it's not. hence the iframe for doing the cross domain communication. the iframe will listen to a localstorage the popup will plant.

Comment: Oath services usually refer the user to another follow-up page after signing in. You can tell it to go to the "refer" page. The localStorage _"variable checker function"_ could be used within your main page.

I will create a demo to show you.

Comment: Perhaps I will finish the demo later, but for now it seems to take a bit too much time. Take a look at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/request_token for information on the callback URL.

Good luck!

Comment: I understand :-) But it needs to be ACROSS domains. I'm creating a service that will be used on other websites. the oAuth happens inside the pop up and closes the pop up on success, then the iframe that is connected to my site will catch the localstorage item set by the pop up. the iframe will send the message back to the cross domain site and all good. or I'll use socket.io.

Comment: Ow! In that case I believe you can alter your server settings to allow cross origin resource sharing (CORS). The client which opened a window to a DOM on your server can then request localstorage of your window object. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control

Comment: that sounds way more complex and in our scenario means more requests (the setInterval is not local, but per request). Thanks again! I'll use Socket.IO with a fallback to an iframe cross domain comms :-)

Answer (score 1):

When a user clicks a sign in button on site1 a pop up is opened from site2.

I'm assuming your using window.open thru an iframe to do this, and that you have already figured out how to bypass most browsers spam blockers etc.

Since you are opening this pop up as a new window, you are now in control of that window, and you can actually send stuff back from the new window.

This will be somewhat pseudo code, but just to make an example!

Lets say a user signs in with a link looking something like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="window.popup=window.open('/twitter/login.php', 'Twitter login', 'width=450,height=500'"</a>
```

Your pop up can now be refferenced by `window.popup`, and inside window.popup the original page is now called the window.opener.

On the same site that opens the popup you have a function, like this:

```
document.handleLogin = function (returnedDataFromPopup) {
    console.log(returnedDataFromPopup);
}
```

After the user has logged in with oAuth, you need to redirect to a new page, this is explained in both the oAuth and Twitter guides, and you need to make that redirect happen inside the popup, and then capture the information from the login on that page and send it back to the original document and the handleLogin function.

Depending on what your using, in most PHP implentations you do something like this to get the data from the login, and this is of course after doing all the token and consumer key stuff:

```
$userinfo = $oAuth->getAttributes(); //or something similar, depends
```

So when redirecting from Twitter to a new page, the new page would look something like:

```
<? php
$userinfo = $oAuth->getAttributes();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
   window.opener.document.handleLogin(<?php echo json_encode($userinfo) ?>);
   window.close();
</script>
```

This will actually run the handleLogin() function on the page that opened the popup, and it will send the userinfo from the popup to that function on the original page and then close the popup window.

I've used this technique with oAuth, OpenID, Google etc. and it works just fine without any need for local storage, cookies or page refresh at all, since you are in control of the popup window you can send information back and forth and you could even change the adress of the popup from the opening document on the fly if you wanted by doing something like this:

```
window.popup.location.href = 'google.com';
```

This is handy in some cases, for instance OpenID will by default close the popup and redirect the document.opener to the page specified, this is not what you want, and to overcome this you would have to open the popup on some random page, preferably an empty page that you control, and then redirect the popup's href to Twitter immediately after the popup is opened.

It all looks very complicated, but it is doable, and if you get this far, you now have the data, an all you have to do is somehow push it to site1 thru the iframe that holds site2. As pushing is'nt really possible without websockets or some sort of event driven server, like node.js, you will probably have to rely on long polling or something else, there are many ways to do this, and I'm sure you'll figure it out, but if you have some control over scripts running on site1, and you obviously have control over site2, then you can actually access some data thru an iframe with a little javascript, but I've never actually done that so I do not know exactly how it works.

It's not really relevant, but I don't really see why it would be useful for someone to login thru your site with an iframe from some other site, and it all seems strange to me, but thats up to you to figure out.

Comment: The missing piece though is: "assuming you're using window.open thru an iframe to do this" - well, actually no, how do you bypass the browser spam blockers? I'm opening the popup from a user click.

Comment: Then there's no problem using the above method. I just read something about iframes between sites and was'nt sure how you were doing this. The spam blockers will usually not stop anything initiated by an actual user click, so thats not a problem either. As I said, when opening a new window you can control that window from the opening page and run functions on the opening page from the popup itself and also send data back to the original page, and that is a much better way of doing it then saving data to local storage and then trying to retrieve that data etc.

Comment: you can't use window.opener if it's cross domain. That's the problem and why I need to also use an iframe. Cross Domain comms can be achieved easily with easyXDM. too bad I doesn't seem to support popups